# How do I stream large text string to client response?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET application with C#.  I need to send over large text string generated on the fly from the server.  How do I stream my response instead of saving everything in memory (ie, in a string variable) then send in everything at the end?

So here is some more information.  I generate my text on the fly like this:

```
List<Row> results = getRows();
```

and I would like to stream out like this:

```
foreach(Row curRow in results){
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Row.data1 + " " + Row.data2);
}
```

Comment: You can write to the Response.Outputstream.  You have to make sure to do Response.Flush() at intervals to send over the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `Response.Flush()` to your existing code to allow this.

```
foreach(Row curRow in results){
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Row.data1 + " " + Row.data2);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}
```

A word of warning though, you will get an exception if you then try to change anything in the headers (cookies, or anything else) after the first `Flush()` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WebAPI or a Handler, the HttpContext.Request has a stream.  Get that stream and read it.  You could read it into a memoryStream or write it to a file stream etc...

Comment: you mean how do stream the Request to another stream?  Where are you wanting to store?  A file?